# Can't run Android-espresso tests

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I have created Espresso test using Espresso Test Recorder, but when I try to run the tests then I get an error or nothing happens.

Usually I get this error:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebugAndroidTest'.
> java.io.IOException: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

When i change in build.gradle

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

to

```
multiDexEnabled false
```

Then it seems I can run the tests but not build the app itself. Anyway when I run the tests, then still nothing happens.

Comment: stay with `multidexenabled true,`but delete ` testInstrumentationRunner="android.support.test.runner....." `. Hope it will work

Comment: check also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34200646/gradle-build-failure-java-io-ioexception-the-output-jar-is-empty